# How to find folders efficiently with specific name using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to use powershell to search for folders with specific name in some path, I have this:

```
get-childitem -path $path -Recurse -Directory -filter $folderName |
foreach{
    write-host $_.FullName
}
```

It works but it is very slow, because there are a lot of files to search for. The case I am dealing is that there are huge amount of files inside the folder I want to find itself. It is wasting time to check for all these files. So I am wondering if there is a way to not dig into this folder when the folder name matches what I want to search for. Cannot do it by removing -recurse tag because the folder I want to search is not necessarily just inside $path but maybe some levels down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to all folders in the path, you could use [`Directory.GetDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$recurse = [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories
[System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($path,$folderName,$recurse)
```